# Loading a particular plugin definition by ID

Tags: 8, plugins

I want to load a plugin definition by its string id within a controller extending ControllerBase. What is the relevant service or class I am looking for?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the plugin manager to fetch a plugin. You only need to find the correct plugin manager service:

```
$type = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.service'); // Fill your own plugin manager service.
$plugin_definition = $type->getDefinition('plugin_id'); // Fill needed plugin id.
```

Comment: Ahh yeah, it hit me right after I posted it. I was having trouble locating the plugin manager. I injected it to the controller via `$container->get('plugin.manager.media_entity.type')` and now I can use it.

Comment: Is there a way to return the plugin configuration as well?

Comment: I would not know, sorry. Though I would think it should be possible. Can't you access it throught the config service? Perhaps there is a pattern?

Comment: Yeah it looks like I could just use the config service, when I thought I would have to look at the plugin definition. Oh well! Now I know anyway.

Comment: The plugin configuration is part of the media type/bundle config entity. http://cgit.drupalcode.org/media_entity/tree/src/Entity/MediaBundle.php, it has getType() to get the plugin, which has getPluginDefinition() and getConfiguration(), you can also use getTypeConfiguration() directly on the media bundle entity